# R - Creating a clustered barplot with two datasets

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart, figure

I'd like to do the following in R.

I have a group of individuals (1 - 50) with two datasets each.  Each dataset (A & B) has values that can be in two categories (Gains, shown in blue; Losses, shown in red).  I'd like to show those two datasets together, as below.  The frequency of Gains/Losses would be in the y axis, where Dataset A would go upward from the x axis, and Dataset B would go downward from the x axis.  I'd like to be able to cluster the barplot either by Individual (as shown below) OR by Gains or Losses (All gains together, then all losses together).

I know how to make clustered barplots in ggplot, but can't figure out how to combine the two datasets as in my image (with dataset A going up and dataset B going down).

[image: An image of what I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something similar to [age pyramids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680075/simpler-population-pyramid-in-ggplot2), only without flipping the coordinates

```
testA <- data.frame(v=as.factor(sample(1:2,1000,replace=T, prob = c(1,5))), dataset='A')
testB <- data.frame(v=as.factor(sample(1:2,1000,replace=T, prob = c(5,1))), dataset='B')

require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)    
ggplot(data=rbind(testA, testB),aes(x=as.factor(v),fill=v)) + 
    geom_bar(subset=.(dataset=="A")) + 
    geom_bar(subset=.(dataset=="B"),aes(y=..count..*(-1)))
```

[image: barplot]