# how I can make a plot with two variable like the one in the picture

Tags: r

I have this data frame
[image: I have this data frame]

I want to make a plot like it with ggplot2
[image: I want to make a plot like it with ggplot2]

which function should i use? or what the name of this plot

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a service for writing code.

Comment: @VadymStupakov I just want to know the name of this plot or which function should i use :)

Comment: @Z.Lin I tried to find out if i can make a plot like it with R

Comment: @VadymStupakov I edited it

Comment: there are two barplots

Comment: separated? @and-bri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simpler population pyramid in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680075/simpler-population-pyramid-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a similar plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

#sample data
df <- data.frame(Age_Range = c('M.25-34', 'M.18-24', 'M.13-17', 'F.25-34', 'F.18-24', 'F.13-17'),
                 Count = c(3356, 2071, 15, 5619, 4342 ,29))

#pre-process dataframe so that it can be used with ggplot2
df$Sex <- gsub('(\\S).*', '\\1',df$Age_Range)
df$Age <- gsub('\\S{2}(.*)', '\\1',df$Age_Range)

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x= Age, y= (Count/sum(Count))*ifelse(Sex=="F",1,-1), fill=Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(y = (Count/sum(Count))*ifelse(Sex=="F",1,-1), label=paste0(round(Count/sum(Count)*100, digits = 2),"%"))) +
  ylab("Your fans") +
  ggtitle("The people who like your Page") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

Hope this helps!