# Plot divergent stacked bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to use `ggplot2` to create divergent stacked bar charts like the one on the right-hand side of the image below?

[image]

#### Data for reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape)

dat <- read.table(text = "    ONE TWO THREE
                  1   23  234 324
                  2   34  534 12
                  3   56  324 124
                  4   34  234 124
                  5   123 534 654",sep = "",header = TRUE)

# reshape data
datm <- melt(cbind(dat, ind = rownames(dat)), id.vars = c('ind'))

# plot
ggplot(datm,aes(x = variable, y = value,fill = ind)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simpler population pyramid in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680075/simpler-population-pyramid-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 8):

Sure, positive values stack positively, negative values stack negatively. Don't use position `fill`. Just define what you want as negative values, and actually make them negative. Your example only has positive scores. E.g.

```
ggplot(datm, aes(x = variable, y = ifelse(ind %in% 1:2, -value, value), fill = ind)) + 
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

If you want to also scale to 1, you need some preprocessing:

```
library(dplyr)
datm %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(value = value / sum(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = ifelse(ind %in% 1:2, -value, value), fill = ind)) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: I am only who noticed that the order of bars is incorrect? 3,4,5 are in reverse order...

Comment: @TomaszWojtas, I usually ignore things that aren't part of OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

An extreme approach might be to calculate the boxes yourself. Here's one method

```
dd <- datm %>% group_by(variable) %>% 
  arrange(desc(ind)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = value/sum(value), right = cumsum(pct), left=lag(right, default=0))
```

then you can plot with

```
ggplot(dd) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=right, xmax=left, ymin=as.numeric(variable)-.4, ymax=as.numeric(variable)+.4, fill=ind)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=levels(dd$variable), breaks=1:nlevels(dd$variable))
```

to get the left plot. and to get the right, you just shift the boxes a bit. This will line up all the right edges of the ind 3 boxes.

```
ggplot(dd %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(left=left-right[ind==3], right=right-right[ind==3])) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=right, xmax=left, ymin=as.numeric(variable)-.4, ymax=as.numeric(variable)+.4, fill=ind)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=levels(dd$variable), breaks=1:nlevels(dd$variable))
```

[image]

So maybe overkill here, but you have a lot of control this way.

Comment: Yes, if the goal is to both fill to 1 and stack pos and neg, I'm pretty sure you need to pre-calculate no matter what. But you should still be able to just once scale all levels to 1, then change to negative and plot with position stack, I think. No need for `geom_rect`?

Comment: @Axeman that seems right. I honestly didn’t know how ggplot would handle stacking negative valued bars. I just wanted to show that you could basically draw whatever you wanted and what that might look like.

Comment: To be fair, IIRC the negative stacking has changed at some point, maybe a year ago or so? Agreed that whenever things don't turn out the way you want, you can draw primitives like `rect`!