# Population pyramid w projection in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I would like to create population pyramids in **R**. I know that there are many examples here on StackOverflow, but I would like to create one that also include population projections,  i.e. with bars for each age group by sex and lines by sex and age group for the projections.

You can see an example here: http://geographyblog.eu/wp/the-worlds-population-pyramid-is-changing-shape/

[image]

If there are some suggestions on how to better illustrate this (e.g. with smoothed lines), they are also welcome, but I would like to indicate both the current situation and the projection. Example data can be found on UN's website: http://esa.un.org/wpp/population-pyramids/population-pyramids_absolute.htm

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note this is a bit of a misleading graphic, since the bars aren't stacked but overlaid. What happens if a 2050 (sky blue) value is smaller than the 2010 (dark blue) value? Is this happening in the lowest left bar? Or is 2010 exactly equal to 2050 there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a little less ad-hoc method uses `ggplot2` and `geom_bar` and `geom_step`.

The data can be extracted from the `wpp2015` package (or `wpp2012`, `wpp2010` or `wpp2008` if you prefer older revisions).

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("wpp2015")

#load data in wpp2015
data(popF)
data(popM)
data(popFprojMed)
data(popMprojMed)

#combine past and future female population
df0 <- popF %>% 
  left_join(popFprojMed) %>%
  mutate(gender = "female")

#combine past and future male population, add on female population
df1 <- popM %>% 
  left_join(popMprojMed) %>%
  mutate(gender = "male") %>%
  bind_rows(df0) %>%
  mutate(age = factor(age, levels = unique(age)))

#stack data for ggplot, filter World population and required years
df2 <- df1 %>%
  gather(key = year, value = pop, -country, -country_code, -age, -gender) %>%
  mutate(pop = pop/1e03) %>%
  filter(country == "World", year %in% c(1950, 2000, 2050, 2100))

#add extra rows and numeric age variable for geom_step used for 2100
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(ageno = as.numeric(age) - 0.5)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  bind_rows(df2 %>% filter(year==2100, age=="100+") %>% mutate(ageno = ageno + 1)) 

df2 
# Source: local data frame [170 x 7]
# 
#    country country_code    age gender  year       pop ageno
#     (fctr)        (int) (fctr)  (chr) (chr)     (dbl) (dbl)
# 1    World          900    0-4   male  1950 171.85124   0.5
# 2    World          900    5-9   male  1950 137.99242   1.5
# 3    World          900  10-14   male  1950 133.27428   2.5
# 4    World          900  15-19   male  1950 121.69274   3.5
# 5    World          900  20-24   male  1950 112.39438   4.5
# 6    World          900  25-29   male  1950  96.59408   5.5
# 7    World          900  30-34   male  1950  83.38595   6.5
# 8    World          900  35-39   male  1950  80.59671   7.5
# 9    World          900  40-44   male  1950  73.08263   8.5
# 10   World          900  45-49   male  1950  63.13648   9.5
# ..     ...          ...    ...    ...   ...       ...   ...
```

With standard `ggplot` functions you can get something similar, adapting from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804394/513463):

[image]

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = age, y = pop, fill = year)) +
  #bars for all but 2100
  geom_bar(data = df2 %>% filter(gender == "female", year != 2100) %>% arrange(rev(year)),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = df2 %>% filter(gender == "male", year != 2100) %>% arrange(rev(year)),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity",
           mapping = aes(y = -pop)) +
  #steps for 2100
  geom_step(data =  df2 %>% filter(gender == "female", year == 2100), 
            aes(x = ageno)) +
  geom_step(data =  df2 %>% filter(gender == "male", year == 2100), 
            aes(x = ageno, y = -pop)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)
```

Note: you need to do `arrange(rev(year))` as the bars are overlays.

With the `ggthemes` package you can get pretty close to the original Economist plot.

[image]

```
library("ggthemes") 
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = age, y = pop, fill = year)) +
  #bars for all but 2100
  geom_bar(data = df2 %>% filter(gender == "female", year != 2100) %>% arrange(rev(year)),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = df2 %>% filter(gender == "male", year != 2100) %>% arrange(rev(year)),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "identity",
           mapping = aes(y = -pop)) +
  #steps for 2100
  geom_step(data =  df2 %>% filter(gender == "female", year == 2100), 
        aes(x = ageno), size = 1) +
  geom_step(data =  df2 %>% filter(gender == "male", year == 2100), 
        aes(x = ageno, y = -pop), size = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  #extra style shazzaz
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs, limits = c(-400, 400), breaks = seq(-400, 400, 100)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme_economist(horizontal = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_economist() +
  labs(fill = "", x = "", y = "")
```

(I am sure you can get even closer, but I have stopped here for now).

Comment: Hi there, I ran the exact same code (with the same data set), and I don't get the projection lines (which use the geom_step function) on the last age group- 100+. I have checked the data frame and it looks alright. Can you please offer any suggestions why would this be and how can I fix it?

Comment: @HM8689 I just ran the code again and get the same plots without any trouble

Comment: thank you for running the code again. That is really odd. What I get is depicted in the question here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078171/geom-step-in-ggplot2-not-working-on-one-of-the-age-groups?noredirect=1#comment106258142_60078171

Comment: This is great. Is there any way I could add the same geom_step to four different facets?

Answer (score 2):

You can cook up something easily using answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245361/population-pyramid-density-plot-in-r) (here I used @timriffle's answer as well as mine).
First some data (from the link you provided):

```
wp <- structure(list(M.1990 = c(325814, 295272, 269351, 265163, 249651, 220027, 196523, 178295, 141789, 115097, 106579, 91763, 77150, 56845, 38053, 25716, 19442), M.2000 = c(319675, 317296, 317072, 290827, 262992, 256378, 241401, 212924, 188905, 169133, 131813, 103162, 90921, 72231, 53449, 32707, 25868), M.2010 = c(328759, 315119, 311456, 312831, 311077, 284258, 255596, 248575, 232217, 202633, 176241, 153494, 114194, 83129, 65266, 43761, 39223), F.1990 = c(308121, 281322, 257432, 254065, 238856, 211943, 188433, 170937, 138358, 112931, 106510, 93425, 82667, 67057, 47679, 37435, 36724), F.2000 = c(298455, 297012, 299757, 277706, 252924, 248127, 233583, 207518, 183646, 165444, 132307, 105429, 96681, 80227, 64956, 45832, 46413), F.2010 = c(307079, 293664, 290598, 293313, 295739, 273379, 247383, 241938, 226914, 201142, 176440, 156283, 121200, 92071, 77990, 56895, 66029)), .Names = c("M.1990", "M.2000", "M.2010", "F.1990", "F.2000", "F.2010"), row.names = c("0-4", "5-9", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80+"), class = "data.frame")

wp
      M.1990 M.2000 M.2010 F.1990 F.2000 F.2010
0-4   325814 319675 328759 308121 298455 307079
5-9   295272 317296 315119 281322 297012 293664
10-14 269351 317072 311456 257432 299757 290598
15-19 265163 290827 312831 254065 277706 293313
20-24 249651 262992 311077 238856 252924 295739
25-29 220027 256378 284258 211943 248127 273379
30-34 196523 241401 255596 188433 233583 247383
35-39 178295 212924 248575 170937 207518 241938
40-44 141789 188905 232217 138358 183646 226914
45-49 115097 169133 202633 112931 165444 201142
50-54 106579 131813 176241 106510 132307 176440
55-59  91763 103162 153494  93425 105429 156283
60-64  77150  90921 114194  82667  96681 121200
65-69  56845  72231  83129  67057  80227  92071
70-74  38053  53449  65266  47679  64956  77990
75-79  25716  32707  43761  37435  45832  56895
80+    19442  25868  39223  36724  46413  66029

xrange <- range(c(0,wp))
yrange <- range(c(0,nrow(wp)))
```

And then the plotting part (in two panels):

```
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
par(mar=c(5,4,4,0))
plot(NA,type="n", main="Men", xlab="", ylab="", xaxs="i", 
     xlim=rev(xrange), ylim=yrange, axes=FALSE, yaxs="i")
rect(xrange[1],yrange[1],xrange[2],yrange[2], col="cadetblue")
abline(v=seq(0,xrange[2],by=1e5), col="white")
# All years with bars you want to represent filled 
# should be entered in reverse order
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$M.2000,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)),
        col="lightblue",border="lightblue")
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$M.1990,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)), 
        col="darkblue",border="darkblue")
# And those you want with just a border, afterwards:
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$M.2010,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)), 
        col=NA,border="darkred",lwd=2)
axis(1, at=c(0,1e5,2e5,3e5), labels=format(c(0,1e5,2e5,3e5),scientific=FALSE))
axis(2, at=1:nrow(wp)-0.5,labels=row.names(wp),las=2)
box()

par(mar=c(5,0,4,4))
plot(NA,type="n", main="Women", xlab="", ylab="", xaxs="i", 
     xlim=xrange, ylim=yrange, axes=FALSE, yaxs="i")
rect(xrange[1],yrange[1],xrange[2],yrange[2], col="cadetblue")
abline(v=seq(0,xrange[2],by=1e5), col="white")
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$F.2000,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)),
        col="lightblue",border="lightblue")
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$F.1990,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)), 
        col="darkblue",border="darkblue")
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$F.2010,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)), 
        col=NA,border="darkred",lwd=2)
axis(1, at=c(0,1e5,2e5,3e5), labels=format(c(0,1e5,2e5,3e5),scientific=FALSE))
axis(4, at=1:nrow(wp)-0.5,labels=row.names(wp),las=2)
box()
```

[image]

To circumvent the issue highlighted by @Spacedman in his comment, you can use an alpha for some of the years.

```
library(scales)
[...]
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$M.1990,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)), 
        col=alpha("darkblue",0.4),border="darkblue")
[...]
polygon(c(0,rep(wp$F.1990,each=2), 0), c(0,0,rep(1:nrow(wp),each=2)), 
        col=alpha("darkblue",0.4),border="darkblue")
[...]
```

[image]